# Can I call a function who's name is stored in a variable?

Tags: php, function, variables

I'm coding an IRC bot, and in it I have an array holding the commands, and an action for each command.

For example, a stored action might be `$array("action" => $irc->say_something())`

Would I be able to call that with `$array['action']` or would I have to do it some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`call_user_func('func', list, of, args)`](http://php.net/call_user_func) or [`call_user_func_array('func', array(containing, arguments))`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array).

As you want to call a class method, you'll have to pass `'func'` not a a string but as an array: `array($instance, 'func')` - in your case: `array($irc, 'say_something')`

Fyi, `$array("action" => $irc->say_something())` makes no sense. But you probably wanted to write `array("action" => $irc->say_something())`. However, this assigns 'action' to the result of the method call - not what you want. See the last paragraph on how the 'action' value should look like to use it as a method pointer.

Comment: In case of an object: `call_user_func(array($irc,'say_something'),array(containing,arguments));`

Comment: Thanks a lot, ThiefMaster. This will relieve a lot of my stress.

Comment: Whoops, almost did forget. Remembered, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
$invocation = array("action" => array(
                                      'func' => array($irc,'say_something'),
                                      'args' => array()));

call_user_func_array($invocation['action']['func'], $invocation['action']['args']);
```

Answer (score 0):

call_user_func http://us.php.net/call_user_func

```
<?php
function barber($type)
{
    echo "You wanted a $type haircut, no problem\n";
}
call_user_func('barber', "mushroom");
call_user_func('barber', "shave");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do something like this:

```
$target = "  blah  ";
$function = "trim";
$trimmed = $function($target);
```

I'd guess that would also work if $function is an array element